# Before open bootstrap modal redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have one button in which i have put below code :

```
<a href="#thread_add_modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="thread_add_id" data-toggle="modal">New Thread</a>
```

Any person is able to create thread once they logged in.Without logged in i cant allow user to create thread.

Javascript :

```
$("#thread_add_id").click(function(){
         var login = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('login')?>";
         if(login == false){
             window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url()?>login/";
         }


     });
```

Problem :

When i am trying to click on New thread without login that time its first open popup and then redirect to login page.
 I dont want to show that popup before logged in.

For that purpose i have done like above.But its not working properly for me.
so any idea, any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all remove `data-toggle="modal"` from anchor tag and add class `clsmodal` we'll open modal on click of jquery event see below snippet i have just pass `var login = true;` to make this fiddle work you just put your PHP code there if login is true modal pop up will show otherwise it will redirected

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
  $(".clsmodal").on("click", function() {
      var login = true;
      if (login == false) {
        window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url()?>login/";
      } else {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      }
 });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg clsmodal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did same before get answer.But somehow your answer seems like good so going to accept it

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Remove Bootstrap attributes from your button

```
<a  class="btn btn-primary" id="thread_add_id" >New Thread</a>
```

**2** Detect if user is logged than redirect. Else refer your modal to show `$('#thread_add_modal').modal('show');`

```
$("#thread_add_id").click(function(){
   var login = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('login')?>";
   if(login == false){
       window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url()?>login/";
   }
   else{
       $('#thread_add_modal').modal('show'); 
   }

});
```